# JAXB Code Inject into Enum Class

Tags: java, enums, jaxb, xsd, tostring

The background problem is when we reflect on a JAXB generated `Enum` class, `toString()` is called which without an `@override` of `toString()` will return `.name()` instead of `.value()`. So, I would like to inject my own `toString()`.

I am unable to inject code into a JAXB generated `Enum` class. Although, I am able to inject code at the top level `complexType` and but not in the inline `Enum` class.

Here is the section of the XSD in question seen below (I have tried absolute and relative):

```
 <jxb:bindings node="/xs:schema/xs:complexType[@name='QueryPgm']/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='STATUS']/xs:simpleType">
```

I use these args:

```
"-verbose -Xinject-code -extension"
```

No errors appear and the output is:

```
  parsing a schema...
  compiling a schema...
  [INFO] generating code
  unknown location
  com/ibm/query/pgm/ObjectFactory
  com/ibm/query/pgm/QueryPgm
  com/ibm/query/pgm/package-info
```

Here is the section of the schema in question:

```
<xs:complexType name="QueryPgm">
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="NAME" type="tns:nameOptions" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />

    <xs:element name="SHOW" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                    <jxb:typesafeEnumClass name="showOptions"/>
                </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="ALL" />
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="STATUS" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                    <jxb:typesafeEnumClass name="statusOptions"/>

                    <jxb:bindings node="/xs:schema/xs:complexType[@name='QueryPgm']/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='STATUS']/xs:simpleType">
                        <ci:code>
                            @Override
                            public String toString() { return this.value();}
                        </ci:code>
                    </jxb:bindings>
                </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>

            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="DB-NOTAVL" />
                <xs:enumeration value="IOPREV" />
                <xs:enumeration value="LOCK" />
                <xs:enumeration value="NOTINIT" />
                <xs:enumeration value="STOSCHD" />
                <xs:enumeration value="TRACE" />
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I would appreciate help or ideas one might have. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any top-level complex type named `QueryPgm`? If there is, please include it, or your complete schema if possible.

Comment: Ok. I see it now after editing.

Comment: Glad you could see it; if there was no QueryPgm I would have gotten a document node does not exist or similar error. Unfortunately I get a clean run, but no code is toString() method is injected.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: David, We did not solve this, I have a few other ideas that I added to our backlog to try when time permits for now we just manually inject the toString() functions, its only 2 or 3 places that we need to do it, not ideal but it works for now.

Answer (score 2):

> today is April 25th, 2019, Not sure if the author stills look for a
>   solution on this kind of issue after 5 years, anyway for whoever
>   cares, it works fine to inject code fragment into generated enum class
>   by jaxb( jvnet plugin).  the reasoning is that we try to support xml
>   and json deserialization by legacy jaxb generated classes with only
>   xml annotations. so we don't really need json annotations by any maven
>   json plugins ( you can not apply both jaxb and json plugin to generate
>   classes with both json and xml annotations. would be a disaster). so
>   those legacy jaxb-generated java classes can be used for json string
>   deserialization ( response coming in).  and enum name() and value() is
>   a pain.  since jaxb has moved to another site with over 400+ issues 
>   https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2 , most of which are not even
>   under active development or to be fixed soon. so I tried below to fix
>   the name() and value() issue, so when toString() of Enum instance is
>   called the 'real value' can be returned instead of the UPPERCASE
>   names. below are some code snippet and plugin information:

binder file:

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation = "locale.xsd" node = "/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:bindings node = "xs:simpleType[@name='localetype']">
        <ci:code>
            <![CDATA[
            @Override
            public String toString() {
            return this.value();
            }
            ]]>
        </ci:code>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

locale.xsd

```
<xs:simpleType name="localetype">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="en_US"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="de_DE"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

main.xsd

```
<xs:element name="customLocale" type="localetype"/>
```

maven plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.14.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/schema</schemaDirectory>
        <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources/schema</bindingDirectory>
        <schemaIncludes>
            <include>*.xsd</include>
        </schemaIncludes>
        <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
        <removeOldOutput>true</removeOldOutput>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <extension>true</extension>
        <args>
            <arg>-Xinject-code</arg>
            <arg>-extension</arg>
            <arg>-XhashCode</arg>
        </args>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                <version>0.6.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                <version>0.6.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-default-value</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

jaxb class generated

```
@XmlType(name = "localetype", namespace = "http://www.xxxx.com/ns/datatype")
@XmlEnum
public enum Localetype {

    @XmlEnumValue("en_US")
    EN_US("en_US"),

    @XmlEnumValue("de_DE")
    DE_DE("de_DE"),


    private final String value;

    Localetype(String v) {
        value = v;
    }

    public String value() {
        return value;
    }

    public static Localetype fromValue(String v) {
        for (Localetype c: Localetype.values()) {
            if (c.value.equals(v)) {
                return c;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(v);
    }


                    @Override
                    public String toString() {
                        return this.value();
                    }    
}
```

jackson testing

```
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.8'
```

jackson client code configuration.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.READ_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING, true);
```

don't forget this: 
     READ_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING  as true ( jackson 2.x version )